# TextToSpeech SynthesizeToFile android function java

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am trying to save the output of TextToSpeech into mp3 file or wav file , I have tested different codes but it never work

The first code i tried :

```
File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/me");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "myData.wav");
    Log.d("Debug ","Path : "+file.getAbsolutePath());
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, textToRead);
    if(textToSpeech.synthesizeToFile(textToRead,params,file.getAbsolutePath()) == textToSpeech.ERROR){
        Log.d("Debug ","file write fail ");
    }else {
        Log.d("Debug ","file write done ");
    }
```

but always the result is "file write fail"

i tried to enter hard coded path to sdcard and it didn't work

```
textToSpeech.synthesizeToFile(textToRead,params,"/sdcard/Android/data/com.orbshine.orbshine/data.wav")
```

Comment: Are you by any chance targeting API 29 (Android 10) or higher? If so, please have a look to the scoped storage section at https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

Comment: Yes but i am testing on API 23

Comment: @Cris that's not how that works. Scoped storage only applies when targeting **and running on** Android 10 or higher. The same is true of all descriptions like that, because lower SDK versions are not aware of the newer features.

Comment: We are assuming that an illegal file path is the reason for synthesizeToFile returning -1.  Has that been verified?  There could be some other reason like a simple typo or empty string send to tts... or non-existent or outdated TTS Engine... who knows.  It may help to relax your requirements until you reach a known-good case and then differentiate from there.

Comment: i tried to hardcode the string that is sent to the tts and it did not work even

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#scoped-storage), *by default, apps targeting Android 10 and higher are given scoped access into external storage, or scoped storage.*

You can either:

1. Target Android 9 (API level 28) or lower (temporary workaround)
2. [Opt-out of scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage) (temporary workaround)

```
<manifest ... >
<!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
     Android 10 or higher. -->
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

3. Migrate your code in order to use the new scoped storage features. This is the recommended solution, as it is the only one that will keep working when targeting API 30 and higher

Comment: I added "android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"" to my mainfest and i targeted APi 28 and still the code does not work 

targetSdkVersion 28